# go on OS X - Two libraries call system functions

Tags: multithreading, macos, user-interface, go, goroutine

I am finding it difficult to write something with more or less common UI at least for Mac. My application has to have [tray icon](https://github.com/getlantern/systray) and be able to show [system notifications](https://github.com/deckarep/gosx-notifier)

The issue is the goroutines themselves. Any call to UI frameworks on Mac requires that the call is made from main thread, or at least in a thread-safe manner.

The issue arise when I am already running UI (well, for GUI application that is a must, no?) and try to show notification. The reason for this seems to be that systray package Init function has to be locked to main thread using `runtime.LockOsThread` and never releases it. Then if I try to show notification which also requires `runtime.LockOsThread` it causes following error:

```
2016-01-11 22:56:27.973 main[30162:4094392] *** Assertion failure in +[NSUndoManager _endTopLevelGroupings], /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Foundation/Foundation-1256.1/Misc.subproj/NSUndoManager.m:359
2016-01-11 22:56:27.974 main[30162:4094392] +[NSUndoManager(NSInternal) _endTopLevelGroupings] is only safe to invoke on the main thread.
2016-01-11 22:56:27.977 main[30162:4094392] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8d42bae2 __exceptionPreprocess + 178
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8bb03f7e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8d42b8ba +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff8cb4c88c -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 198
    4   Foundation                          0x00007fff8cad24c1 +[NSUndoManager(NSPrivate) _endTopLevelGroupings] + 170
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff8514206a -[NSApplication run] + 844
    6   main                                0x0000000004166200 nativeLoop + 128
    7   main                                0x0000000004165bca _cgo_8c6479959095_Cfunc_nativeLoop + 26
    8   main                                0x000000000405a590 runtime.asmcgocall + 112
)
2016-01-11 22:56:27.977 main[30162:4094392] *** Assertion failure in +[NSUndoManager _endTopLevelGroupings], /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Foundation/Foundation-1256.1/Misc.subproj/NSUndoManager.m:359
2016-01-11 22:56:27.978 main[30162:4094392] An uncaught exception was raised
2016-01-11 22:56:27.978 main[30162:4094392] +[NSUndoManager(NSInternal) _endTopLevelGroupings] is only safe to invoke on the main thread.
```

Is there a workaround that? All I could think of so far is to put UI and Notifications into separate binaries and make them to communicate with main over some sort of IPC. But I may be missing something.

Comment: I think it's way more common to write a web-interface for your go application, e.g. syncthing does that. You could achieve notifications with HTML5 (maybe?) and an icon with a simple url, or something like that

Comment: @mrd0ll4r and how would one add tray icon with HTML5? Afaik there is no way to do such thing. There is no window per se (yet). But only tray icon and notifications. Introducing entire web interface is not in the scope of this app

Comment: I think this is usually done with 2 processes and some IPC.

Comment: You did not tell us much, but from your question it appears you already use *something* to do the UI. I would then made that *something* accept a request to show things in the system tray icon, and then made your Go side do those requests. Exact implementation is highly dependent on what is used for the UI but I think if you'll ask a proper (that is, with much more details provided -- to stay away from "The XY Problem") question on the [go-nuts mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts) we'll be able to sort that problem out somehow.

Comment: @kostix I not just use "something" but give direct reference to the libraries that I am using (check the links) since this may help someone with a knowledge to answer this question. This is a well known problem on OS X and there was no solution that I found so far. So someone familiar with the topic will have no difficulty understanding question and issue in it. Don't see how I could improve question apart of giving code snippets which again is not necessary as issue is well known.

Comment: Sure I did check the links; found nothing about the "UI" part. Hence I assumed your UI was something implemented in C or ObjC (or whatever). I, for one, still have no idea how the UI part is implemented. All in all, it's your question so if you think everything is okay with it, it's indeed probably okay for you. Hope you'll get the help sought.

Comment: @kostix well, any advice on how to improve question is appreciated. Just saying "need to improve" does not show what's not understood. I will try to add code snippet later.

Comment: @AlexKey ah yes, I mistook tray icons for something like pinned taskbar entries on windows, or an entry in the dock for OSX, sorry about that. I'd still recommend to realize most of your UI as a web app. You could fix your problem by porting everything except the tray icon stuff...

Answer (score 3):

Since there is not enough traction on this question I've decided to post my own solution I found while trying to workaround this issue. This won't be marked as answer yet since someone else may provide better solution.

I have moved one of the UI processes (namely part that uses systray) into another binary and call it using `cmd := exec.Command(...)` and `cmd.Start()` then I pipe `stdin` and `stdout` and communicate with this child process through those.

The example code can be found on [Github](https://gist.github.com/akamensky/48ad7009af2cd9474447). **Warning** there is an error in this gist where after child exits main process will start burning through CPU cycles. Feel free to fix it yourself.

The reason why I did not want to go through with RPC is because this will become slightly too complex to what I want to achieve and does not provide easy way to do two way communication.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the two libraries that you are using both correctly use `runtime.LockOSThread` to make main-thread-only API calls; unfortunately, to use more than one such library, you'll have to do something fancier than the example code that either provides.  You'll need to write your own main thread / `main.Main`-invoked message loop that handles calls to multiple MTO APIs.

[`runtime.LockOSThread`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#LockOSThread) is part of the solution to operating with APIs such as this; the golang wiki [has a page](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/LockOSThread) about how to use it to interact with "call from main thread only" APIs.

An extremely short description of how your program should change:

You'll want to use [`runtime.LockOSThread`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#LockOSThread) in `main.init` to make sure that the main thread is running `main.Main`; `main.Main` should be refactored into two parts:

1. starts a goroutine or goroutines that run what previously was in `main.Main`;
2. enters a message loop receiving messages to take certain main-thread actions on one or more channels

Comment: I've read description of LockOsThread. The problem is that using two libraries that both require their current thread being locked to system thread causes app to crash. This is because while one thread is locked second one tries to lock. There is no global mutex in LockOsThread. So need some solution to this problem. As said IPC is one of them where I can put those two libs each in separate process so that each can lock independently. But that is going to be big mess. Maybe there is better solution?